# Android SQLite Drop Table

Tags: android

What is the proper way of dropping a table in Android (using sqlite)?

Do i write

```
db.execSQL("drop table myTable;");
```

In the sqlitehelper class or in the main activity Oncreate method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a string as shown below:

```
public static final String DROP_TABLE_NAME = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME;
```

Call this as shown below in onUpgrade() method, in the class where you have inherited SQLiteOpenHelper Class:

```
db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE_NAME);
```

Hope this helps.